# SwiftUI. Error while fetching html from a website: "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'"

Tags: swift, web-scraping, swiftui, try-catch

I am trying to scrape a website to get some information, except I keep running into the problem where I get the error:

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result
> builder 'ViewBuilder'

I have tried fixing this without success.
Here is my code:

```
do {
    let contents = try String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://app.universaltennis.com/profiles/3456")!)
                
}catch{
   print("Oh no...")        
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this error? The error is highlighted over the "do" statement, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: Executable code like this needs to be inside a function or closure, like inside a `Button`'s `action` parameter. Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Don't put that code in a SwiftUI View of any kind it should be an a `class` and then you can make it an `ObservableObject` you likely have it in a `body` right now

Comment: Inside the catch add: `print(error)` to see what the problem is

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.